Evaluating $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(y-a \ln(y+a)+c)}}dy$
I am trying to solve this nonlinear ODE equation:
$y''=\frac{y}{y+a}$
I tried to $v=y'$ and it gives me
$v=\pm\sqrt{2(y-a \ln(y+a)+C_0)}=\frac{dy}{dx}$
which requires me to solve
$x=\pm \int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(y-a \ln(y+a)+C_0)}}}dy$
I am stuck here and wondering if there is no analytical solution to this equation. Any idea? An approximate solution here is acceptable too.

From what I found this is a Second-Order Autonomous Differential Equation,
$$f(y)=\frac{y}{y+a}$$
$$\color{red}{\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1 + 2\int f(y),dy}},dy=C_2\pm x}$$
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1 + 2\int \frac{y}{y+a},dy}},dy=C_2\pm x$$
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1 + 2\left(y-a\ln(a+y)\right)}},dy=C_2\pm x$$
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2y-2a\ln(a+y)+C_1}},dy=C_2\pm x$$
